# show images/blocks horizontally

Tags: css, html, styles

I'm trying to get a div to show images/blocks without overflowing y-axis but overflowing x-axis.

here is my attempt with no luck 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/VJX3p/1/

Answer (score 3):

Apply `white-space: nowrap;` style to child div images will align horizontally

```
#child {
  position:relative;
  background:#fde;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#parent {
  position:relative;
  background:#fd2;
  width:500px;
  height:350px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#child {
   position:relative;
  white-space:nowrap;
  background:#fde;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Just so if anyone was interested in knowing the final answer. Thank you all and sreejithsdev `white-space: nowrap;` is the trick.

Comment: Glad I checked up on this.  Good use of white-space attribute here!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with just CSS.  The following code will get the vid to overflow only on the x-axis:

```
#parent {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
#child {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 2650px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 9px;
  display: block;
}
```

To better explain what is going on, here is my thought process:
1) First we float the images to the left so that they will line up next to each other (only if there is enough space, which we will set later).  I set a margin-right of 9 px to space out the images.  I set the image as display block out of habit (I don't believe it is required).

2) In order to get all the images in one line we either need to give #parent or #child a width of 2650px.  I decide to set #child with 2650px so that I can then set #parent to overflow-x (thus creating the scroll area).  I also have to set overflow: hidden to #child to fix the "clearfix" problem that occurs because all of it's children are floated.

Please note that if you add an image or change the size of the images then you will have to recalculate the width value of #child.  You can do this dynamically on the server side or on the client side through javascript if you're dynamically loading more images.

Comment: Thanks richardaday what if the images are added dynamically. I tried setting the child box to 100% and also auto but didn't do the trick !! any suggestions

Comment: I just edited my comment to explain the thought process behind coming up with the CSS.  If the images are added dynamically then you will have to use Javascript to find out the width of all the child elements (including padding, margin, and borders).  Add them together and set that as the new width for #child.

Comment: By the way, setting a child element to width of 100% only forces the child element to take the exact width of the parent element.  So if the parent element is 800px wide, setting the child to 100% width will make it 800px wide.